# What is a "non-weak zeroing reference"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsnotificationcenter, osx-elcapitan

In the [OS X v10.11 beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016227-SW1), I find the following:

> NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated. If the observer is able to be stored as a zeroing-weak reference the underlying storage stores the observer as a zeroing weak reference. Alternatively, if the object cannot be stored weakly (because it has a custom retain/release mechanism that would prevent the runtime from being able to store the object weakly) **the object is stored as a non-weak zeroing reference**. This means that observers are not required to un-register in their deallocation method. [emphasis mine]

This doesn't make sense to me. If it is a non-weak reference, wouldn't it be a strong reference, then? So the NSNotificationCenter would still be an owner, so the object wouldn't deallocate (until manually unregistered), so it's nonsensical in this context to say it's "zeroing".

If this is referring to a sort of `__unsafe_unretained` reference, then the question is…how then would NSNotificationCenter avoid messaging a zombie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for this lies deep within the objective-c runtime, and how `__weak` variables actually work. To explain, let's look a little bit at `objc_weak.mm`:

```
id 
weak_read_no_lock(weak_table_t *weak_table, id *referrer_id) 
{
    ...

    if (! referent->ISA()->hasCustomRR()) {
        if (! referent->rootTryRetain()) {
            return nil;
        }
    }
    else {
        BOOL (*tryRetain)(objc_object *, SEL) = (BOOL(*)(objc_object *, SEL))
            object_getMethodImplementation((id)referent, 
                                           SEL_retainWeakReference);
        if ((IMP)tryRetain == _objc_msgForward) {
            return nil;
        }
        if (! (*tryRetain)(referent, SEL_retainWeakReference)) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return (id)referent;
}
```

As you can see, when custom `-retain` and `-release` methods are used by an object, it's not guaranteed that they support weak references at all (also note that you can use an entirely different object for an object's weak references, though that's a topic for another time).

This is because weak references are cleaned up by `objc_destructInstance`, which calls `objc_clearDeallocating`, which calls `weak_clear_no_lock`.

Now, `objc_destructInstance` is NOT required to be called by custom object implementations, although most objects will call it.

Thus, the runtime allows you to implement the method `-allowsWeakReference` (and `retainWeakReference`) to disable weak references to your object, in which case it's most likely zero'd out by swizzling `-dealloc` on the object. Of course, this is all implementation details, so NSNotificationCenter could have it's own innovative way of doing things, but that's my best guess without attempting to disassemble NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: For an example implementation of the kind of swizzling i'm referring to, take a look at [MAZeroingWeakRef](https://github.com/mikeash/MAZeroingWeakRef/).

Comment: Plenty thorough answer, and exactly the sort of explanation I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> Declaring a property as strong makes that property a strong reference.
>   Declaring it as weak uses a zeroing weak reference. The
>   **unsafe_unretained** modifier uses a non-zeroing weak reference

Briefly: `non-weak zeroing reference` == `unsafe_unretained refernce`

Reference:

https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html
http://www.jessesquires.com/UIKit-changes-in-iOS-9/

Comment: This question is different than the more common case. Not "what is a non-zeroing weak reference". The question here is "what is a non-weak zeroing reference".

Comment: You mean they're difference ?